# Smartbear Code Collaborator GUI client not recognizing Subversion repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, code-collaborator

I'm using Windows 7 Professional and Subversion with TortoiseSVN, and trying to use Code Collaborator v6.0.6013.

When I start up the GUI client, I need to tell it what the SCM configuration is.  The pulldown menu only has AccuRev, CMVC, CVS, and ClearCase, so I specify a Subversion project in the local location, so it can auto-detect.  On this computer, it doesn't resulting in SCM of (none), Configuration of (none), on any of several directories, all of which I can do all the usual Subversion stuff on.

It works perfectly on every other system in the office, detecting Subversion and some useful option settings.  It doesn't work on this one, despite restarting the system and uninstalling/reinstalling the client several times.  I haven't found any references to this sort of thing online or on Smartbear's site.

Does anybody know what might be going on?  Any suggestions of things to try next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the commandline subversion client; the Code Collaborator GUI uses it on your working copy behind the scenes.  Once installed, it needs to be either on the path, or you can specify the path to the svn executable in the GUI.

Yes, it would be nice if the client could use Tortoise, but Tortoise is just lacking in functionality from a commandline perspective.

Disclaimer: I work for SmartBear Software, makers of Code Collaborator.

Comment: Always nice to get a nice, quick answer from the source.  Thank you very much.

Comment: David, do you recommend any particular command line svn client?  SilkSVN, collabnet or some other? Any will do?

Comment: Code Collaborator uses the xml output format of the commandline clients to maintain forward compatibility - we know that collabnet and SilkSVN both work.

Comment: Had the same issue. I installed the SilkSVN version on my end. SilkSVN will automatically add svn.exe to your path. Nothing else to do. Worked.

Comment: The simplest option to specify the path to our SVN binaries would really be a nice addition...

Comment: You can do that too; http://codecollaborator.smartbear.com/docs/manual/8.0/subversion_ccollab.html#configuration is the manpage you want.

Answer (score -1):

Change you language to United States in Setting->Language&Region->Region, then restart your ccollabtray client will work.

Comment: This problem from 8 years ago was not caused by a language setting. It was already resolved by adding a missing command-line program, as you can see from the accepted answer.